# Bug Fix for Calling a FileWriter to be sorted multiple Times

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, methods, filewriter

I have written a method to generate numbers 1-2000,2000-1 and random numbers on three separate files. One file called best which is 1-2000, worst for 2000-1 and random for random. That's Works!

Then I made insertion, selection, and bubble sorting. That works as well.

When I call on the different methods it will not sort it after one algorithm has sorted them. I looked at the file and I see that it does not change the file itself. I do not know what to do

What I have tried was calling on the method before the algorithms were written. For example 
creatingfile() ;
bubblesort(worst);
I feel terrible for posting so much of the code but I dont know how to show you I am not trying to make someone make my code. I just need help for one part of it.

```
//here is a shorten bubbe sorting (just using one to be minimal) 
public static void bubbleSort(int[] array) {
     int numberOfItems = array.length;
     int comp=0,exch=0,temp=0;
     boolean cont = true;
     for (int pass=1; pass != numberOfItems; pass++)   {
         if (cont) {
             cont = false;
             for (int index=0; index != numberOfItems-pass; index++) {
                 comp++;
                 if (array[index]> array[index+1]) {
                     exch++;
                     temp = array[index];
                     array[index] = array[index+1];
                     array[index+1] = temp;
                     cont = true;
 ...
             break; // end outer if
     }
     System.out.println ("comparsion: " + comp); // end inner if
     System.out.println ("exchange: " + exch); // end inner for
```

```
creatTestFiles method 
int[] best = new int[2000];
    ;
  try {
        for (int i = stop; i >= stop1; i--) {
               int worstnum =i+1;
                 worstText +=worstnum + " ";
             }
             // write worst case to respective file
             fw.write(worstText);
             fw.close();
 }...
```

```
   main method() 
createTestFiles();

 bubbleSort(worst);
insertionSort(worst);
selctionSort(worst);
```

INSERTION SORT
comparsion: 1999000
exchange: 1997001

BUBBLE SORT
comparsion: 3997
exchange: 1999

SELECTION SORT
comparsion: 1999000
exchange: 1999

// here bubble is on top (all different) I am not sure why.
BUBBLE SORT
comparsion: 1999000 . 
exchange: 1999000

INSERTION SORT
comparsion: 1999
exchange: 0

SELECTION SORT
comparsion: 1999000
exchange: 199
So if I put the first algorithms, that's the only one that will sort it. The next one will not.

Comment: My guess is that you read the file into an array and then sort that array. If you pass an object then you only pass a copy of the reference, not of the whole object, so if you modify that object via this reference the original gets changed. That's why only the first one has to sort. Pretty sure if your calls would be `bubbleSort(worst.clone()); insertionSort(worst.clone()); selectionSort(worst.clone());` you won't see that effect.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But you mean do you mean.clone(). Would that make a copy of the file because my array will read the numbers and sort them in the specified array. What would .clone do then?

Comment: You will sort a clone of your array and not the original. An array of primitives is an object too. It has nothing to do with the file, if you would read the file each time into the array it would work too.

Comment: still confused but thanks for commenting.